# Function returning odd value

Tags: c++

I am new to programming and I was recently assigned a pretty hard code. I've been trying to finish it but I am stumped.

My function prototype is

```
int getNumAccidents(int);
```

My main call is:

```
int north;
int south;
int east;
int west;
int central;
cout << "Please enter the value for North\n";
getNumAccidents(north);
cout << "the number of accidents in the north are:\n" << north;
break;
```

And my function is:

```
int getNumAccidents(int value)
{
    cin >> value;
    return value;
}
```

It compiles fine, but I get an unexpected return when I input data. I entered 32 and the return from my function is 4591493..... why?

Comment: You never used the returned value

Comment: north = getNumAccidents(north);

Comment: ***I am new to programming and I was recently assigned a pretty hard code.*** BTW, this is about as easy as it gets for c++.

Comment: I know but like I said I am new. any clarification on why that large value was returned? Where did it come from?

Comment: Since you did not set the value of north, you got a garbage value from memory and printed that garbage value. c++ does not initialize local simple types with 0.

Comment: Also the int value in `int getNumAccidents(int value)` is a parameter passed by value so it will not change north. Maybe you should rewrite the function to not pass the value and just use the return instead of throwing it away.

Comment: What I mean by that is `int getNumAccidents() { int value; cin >> value; return value; }` Then use it by `north = getNumAccidents();`

Answer (score 3):

Try like this

```
int north;
int south;
int east;
int west;
int central;
cout << "Please enter the value for North\n";
north=getNumAccidents(north);
cout << "the number of accidents in the north are:\n" << north;
break;
```

Comment: Why so serious ? @EdHeal relax man. this is not the end of the world.

Comment: I didn't suggest him nothing , i just shown him his mistake point. By the way Thanks for the down vote.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
void getNumAccidents(int &value)
{
    cin >> value;
}
```

As you need to return the input to main.

Answer (score 0):

there is anothor way.

```
void getNumAccidents(int *value)
{
    if (value)
    {
        cin >> *value;
    }
}
```

use like this

```
int value = 0;
getNumberAccidents(&value);
```

Comment: Its C++ - So use reference instead - gets over the problem of passing in `nullptr`